# sql server get max value integer in a string from two tables

Tags: php, mysql, sql, sql-server

i have this sql query for mysql that works well. the query finds in 2 tables wich is the max numeric value from both and returns the value good in mysql, i have to do the same query in sql server but tells me an error **syntax error near cast, expects as**

the query is the next :

```
SELECT MAX(CAST(RIGHT(nrt, 5) AS UNSIGNED)) 
FROM
(
  SELECT nrt from asp where nrt != ' ' and nrt is not null 
  UNION ALL 
  SELECT nrt from asp_historic where nrt != ' ' and nrt is not null
) as subQuery
```

there is a way to do that the this query runs?

Comment: change UNSIGNED to INT

Comment: works but returns me one value that is not an int, there is a way to dscard the values thar are only text without numbers??

Comment: provide us with sample data and desired result please

Comment: table asp: 12FG12122,MF23112,ERR-AS,.... the other table (table asp_hist): 16AB12125,13453..., i have to get the max value for each table only the values that have 5 digits in right substring or the values that have only digits discarding all the values that not have this condition.

Comment: can you put the sample data in the question with proper format please? This is hard to read

Answer (score 0):

I would start with no conversion at all:

```
SELECT MAX(RIGHT(nrt, 5)) FROM asp WHERE nrt <> ' ' and nrt is not null 
UNION ALL 
SELECT nrt FROM asp_historic WHERE nrt M< ' ' and nrt is not null
```

This assumes that `nrt` has at least 5 characters.

If not, convert to an integer:

```
SELECT CAST(MAX(RIGHT(nrt, 5)) as int) FROM asp WHERE nrt <> ' ' and nrt is not null 
UNION ALL 
SELECT nrt FROM asp_historic WHERE nrt <> ' ' and nrt is not null
```

EDIT:

This question appears to be about MySQLs implicit conversions.  I might suggestion:

```
SELECT MAX(CAST(LEFT(nrt + ' ', PATINDEX(nrt, '%[^0-9]%') - 1) as int))
. . .
```

Comment: the nrt value can be a string formed by only 5 numbers, letters and numbers,etc, i would get only the values that in right part have 5 digits or values that have only 5 digits discarding the rest,, and with the result of the 2 tables, get the max value

Answer (score 0):

Below is the same code for **SQL Server** ...

```
SELECT MAX(RIGHT(ABS(nrt), 5))
    FROM
    (
      SELECT nrt from asp where nrt <> ' ' and nrt is not null 
      UNION ALL 
      SELECT nrt from asp_historic where nrt <> ' ' and nrt is not null
    ) as subQuery
```

Are you looking for `nrt != ' ' and nrt is not null` ?

I think it should be `OR` condition instead of `AND`.

Comment: sql server tells me that that can't convert varchar to float

Comment: What is the data type of column nrt ? what data does it contains ?